# Matlab multiple stacked plots

Tags: matlab, plot

I've never seen a plot like the following (the plot in (a) ). Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: This is effectively a form of [waterfall plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot). The most famous use of this type of plot might be [this pulsar data](http://www.itsokaytobesmart.com/post/96415755382/do-math-realizes-joy-division-did-some-real). See [`waterfall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html). Doing this with multiple overlapping axes (or faking them) will take a bit of work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the profile page of @Ander Biguri

> Matlab can even make your dinner, if you know how to use it.

Which answers the question, if this is even possible ;-)

All we need is basic knowledge of the [`axes`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) command - the rest is just tweaking to make it look nice. Let's have a look at it:

We'll start off by creating some sample data:

```
t = 100:220;
x1 = -(10*(t-130)).^2;
x2 = -(10*(t-150)).^2;
x3 = -(10*(t-170)).^2;
```

Then we'll create an initial figure with a white background

```
fig = figure(1);
set(fig,'Color','w');
```

Now we can create a new axes object and plot `x1` on it:

```
ax(1) = axes('Position',[0.1,0.1,0.6,0.6]);
plot(ax(1),t,x1+10^4*rand(size(x1)),'-k',t,x1,'-r');
```

We'll remove the box around the axes, so only the x- and y-axes remain. Further we resize the plot, so we'll have enough space for the other two plots. We also set the color to none, i.e. transparent.

```
set(ax(1),'Color','none');
set(ax(1),'Box','off');
set(ax(1),'Position',[0.1,0.1,0.6,0.6]);
```

Now we need to create the second graph. We'll just create another axes object at a position which we like:

```
ax(2) = axes('Position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6]);
plot(ax(2),t,x2+10^4*rand(size(x2)),'-k',t,x2,'-r');
set(ax(2),'Color','none');
set(ax(2),'Box','off');
```

and so on:

```
ax(3) = axes('Position',[0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6]);
plot(ax(3),t,x3+10^4*rand(size(x3)),'-k',t,x3,'-r');
set(ax(3),'Color','none');
set(ax(3),'Box','off');
```

And simple as that, we get something that doesn't even look that bad:

[image: the result]

Comment: I haven't seen this reference before! I'm flabbergasted and delighted! :P

Answer (score 4):

Using multiple `waterfall` plots, as Horchler suggested:

```
 %// create some sample data
t=10:20:110;
x=0:1:200;
Y=bsxfun(@(x,t) normpdf(x,t,20),x,t.');                                                         %//' fix the code formatting on SO!!

%// Make a colormap to to set the colour of the lines
colormap([1 0 0;0 0 0]);caxis=[0 1];

%// Plot the first set of lines (red ones)
h1=waterfall(x,t,Y,zeros(size(Y)));
set(h1,'FaceColor','none','LineWidth',2) %// tweak the properties
hold on

%// Plot the second set of lines (black lines), just the red lines with some noise
h2=waterfall(x,t,Y+0.002*(rand(size(Y))-0.5),ones(size(Y)));
set(h2,'LineWidth',2)
hold off

view([16 28])
```

we can get this:
[image]